# Pass a variable from an open form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, Form1 and Form2. Form1 has a variable int x. When the program is executed, Form1 is hidden and Form2 is shown; however i need to call the variable from the existing Form1.

I know the method to call the variable by calling a new instance of Form1.

```
     Form1 r = new Form1();
     r.x = 20;
```

But I want to know how to do it for an already opened Form1.

Take several cases, like if there are multiple variables that are called from Form1, by several forms (Form2, Form3, Form4 etc...). Any variable can be called from Form1 by the forms. Also, forms can call variables from other forms (Like if Form1 and Form2 is open, then Form3 can call variables from Form1 AND Form2)

I know its a huge list, but would really appreciate if anyone can find a good way to implement it.

Comment: Do you just want to access the value of the variable on form1 or you want to pass that value to form2.???

Comment: I want to pass the value as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in following ways,

in my case form1 is form4 and form2 is form5. please consider, :)

1. ```
    //code on form4:

   // this is by passing the reference of the form to other form
   public partial class Form4 : Form

   {

   public int a { get; set; }
   public int b { get; set; }

   public Form4()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       a = 5;
       b = 6;

       Form5 frm5 = new Form5();

       frm5.frm4 = this;

       this.Close();

       frm5.Show();
   }
    }

   // code on form5

   public Form4 frm4 { get; set; }

   private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       int x = frm4.a;
       int y = frm4.b;
   }
   ```
2. Also you can have a class file in which the instance of the `form1` will be `static`, so that you can use that instance on `form2` to refer to the `form1's` properties.

Let me know, if it does not solve your problem.

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: Nice answer. How do you declare frm4 on Form5?

Comment: I am sorry, i have forgotten to mention that. I have edited the code. Just check it out again. And if you like the answer and found the answer good, then vote the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to have a reference to the "already opened" form1 instance, so that you can reference the value of x on that form.

So, lets say that Form2 instantiates the hidden form1. You will have to have a reference in form2 to the form1, to reference the variable.

OK, Lets say this is the code for form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 f;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f = new Form1
                {
                    Visible = false
                };
        int x = f.X;
    }
}
```

and then code for form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        X = 20;
    }
}
```

and you need to ensure that the form luanched from the program class is

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
}
```

Comment: I did think of this as well, but i want Form1 to be the first form to launch; instead of launching Form2 first and then hiding it.

Comment: OK, so you wish to luanch form1 first, then form2 from form1, and then hide form1?

Comment: yes, then call variables with values in them from Form1. Calling a new instance of Form1 will give me the default values of the variables

Comment: OK, lets step back a bit, why do you need to luanch Form1 first, then hide it, and show form2? Are you planning to use the values from form1 with multiple other forms? Why not use a singleton approach then rather?

Comment: Form2 solely depend on the variables from From1. Form1 is kind of like a log-in page; Form2 changes depending on the user logged in

Answer (score 1):

Create a public property on the form itself. Have the get accessor return the form value. You can call it like this. `Form1.MyProperty;`

```
public string MyPrperty {
  get {
      return Form1.txtExample.text;
  }
}
```

### EDIT:

You can return a dictionary of all of those values if you have that many to return at a time. I would seriously consider rethinking your form if you have 20-40 values being filled. That sounds like a poor user experience to me.

Comment: I did consider this. But what if you have multiple variables (string, float, bool, char, int etc) on Form1?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can create a public property for each one you want to return.

Comment: Form properties are just like any other class property. The back-end of your code is still just a class that behaves like any other class.

Comment: Suppose i have around 20-40 variable that i want to pass from Form1 to From2. I don't think its a feasible idea to create the code for all 40 variables...

Comment: Well, you can return a dictionary of all the values as a property. That way, you have all of the values in a single call. 20-40 variables returned makes me think you should rethink your design, possibly. If it's a form a user fills out, that's A LOT of fields to fill out at a time.

Comment: Check the edit. Not necessarily that the user fills in the data, data might be something from the website or db...

Comment: You can still handle it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether which form is opened or closed. Your ultimate goal is to access a member from Form1 in Form2 isn't it? If that is the case when you create an instance of your Form2, do it like this

```
    Form1 objForm1 = new Form1();
    Form2 obj = new Form2(objForm1);
```

so that in form 2 class looks like this

```
    class Form2: Form
    {
         private Form1 form1Object;
         public Form2(Form1 obj)
         {
              form1Object = obj;
         }

         private void SomeMethodInForm2()
         {
              //Here you can access the variable in form1 like
              form1Object.PropertyNameYouWantToAccess;
         }
     }
```

The form 1 class can look like this

```
     class Form1: Form
    {
         public int PropertyNameYouWantToAccess{get;}

     }
```

Comment: Suppose i have around 20-40 variable that i want to pass from Form1 to From2. I don't think its a feasible idea to create the code for all 40 variables...

Comment: you dont have to pass 40 - 50 variables , you just have to pass the object which contains those variables. Either you have one member or 50 member if you could pass the instance then using the instance you can access all the members.  If you need 40 variables then you have to create it , how can you achieve this otherwise.I hope i m not confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a reason that you wouldn't try `System.Properties.Settings.Default`
accessible from Project Menu --> Properties in visual studio...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are looking for [System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eh13dca9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property which holds all the open forms in an array.

What you need to do is to check the type of each form and if it is equivalent to `Form1` access the variable's value. Also, to access the variable outside the form you need to set its access modifier to either `Public` or make a corresponding property for it.

**EDIT**

Here is a sample code: (untested)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

public int X;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    X = 100;

    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Show();

    this.Hide();
}  
}



public partial class Form2 : Form
{

int local_X = 0;

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(Form f in System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms)
   {
      if(typeof(f) == typeof(Form1))
    {
       local_X = f.X;   // access value here and set in local variable
    }
   }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Value of X is : " + local_X); // Show alert for value of variable on button click
}

}
```

**EDIT**

Or you can use **constructor overloading** to accomplish this task:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

public int X;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    X = 100;

    Form2 frm = new Form2(x); // pass variable to form2, if multiple values pass int array
    frm.Show();

    this.Hide();
}  
}



public partial class Form2 : Form
{

int local_X = 0;

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

// Overloading of constructor
public Form2(int X) // if multiple values pass int array
{
    InitializeComponent();
    local_X = x;  // capture value from constructor in class variable.
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // no need to iterate here for now due to overloading value get passed during initialization.
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Value of X is : " + local_X);  // display value if alert box.
}

}
```

Comment: Can you give some coding for it? I need to use the variable throughout the class, not just in a function. I don't think you can call the Application.OpenForms in the Class, only in functions

Comment: On FormLoad event of `Form2` use `OpenForms` property and get value from `Form1` and assign it to a local variable. So you can access it through out the class.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: This would mean that i have to call the foreach loop every time i needed to get the value of the variable. Is there a way to declare that 'f' is the Form1 that is already opened when Form2 loads?

Comment: No, for open forms you need to iterate and filter the required form or you can use another way i am adding to my solution.

Comment: Good idea. However what if i have more than one datatype, like string bool, decimal etc? Also what if Form2 receives variables from other forms?

Comment: then instead of int array you can pass object array, no matter who calls form2 it just knows the values passed to it.

Comment: In accepted solution you always need to declare FormX's instance in Form2 and assign `this` to it. so if 5 forms call Form2 5 variables will need to be declared or alternatively typecasting from base to derived would help. Using my way you don't have to care about such overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the situation.You have multiple forms in your application and you want to do access several variables these forms.

My guess is,

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static object MyVariable1 { get; set; }
    public static object MyVariable2 { get; set; }
}
```

So you can access variables everywhere in your project.